# "Lease" and "surrender" meaning. "They moved out and the lease was surrendered."

Tags: meaning, sentence

What does it mean:

> They moved out and the lease was surrendered.

Does it mean that previous leasers gave back the landlord their lease document (their contract with landlord), or it means that as soon as previous leasers moved out new ones moved in almost at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

There is no mention of new tenants.  I would say that "their lease was surrendered" means that they gave up the right to return: if they want to return in the future, they would have to negotiate a new lease.